# What are the correct Permissions for docker in docker as another user?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, go-cd

I'm trying to enable my docker instance to build other docker images from a CI server. My agent spins up a container, and i have my macs docker.sock mounted into the container.

- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

When inside the container and running as root, i am able to download and run containers:

```
root@b6da92395273:/godata/pipelines# docker run helloworld
019300c8a437: Pull complete
dc9253de2674: Pull complete
43208f2470b6: Pull complete
eb4d21c66200: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:6797efb60e8efb49ad1ed48d9904bd23ccdb87fdeba10c0b057986fefaf2756b
Status: Downloaded newer image for XXXXXX
```

However, my build agent runs as user 'go', while running as 'go' i get the following error:

```
go@b6da92395273:/godata/pipelines$ docker run helloworld
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.29/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I have the following inside my Dockerfile

```
  addgroup -g 1000 go && \
  adduser -D -u 1000 -G go go && \
```

When i exec into the container - as root - i see:

```
bash-4.3#  cat /etc/group | grep go
go:x:1000:go
bash-4.3#  cat /etc/group | grep root
root:x:0:root
bin:x:1:root,bin,daemon
daemon:x:2:root,bin,daemon
sys:x:3:root,bin,adm
adm:x:4:root,adm,daemon
disk:x:6:root,adm
wheel:x:10:root
floppy:x:11:root
dialout:x:20:root
tape:x:26:root
video:x:27:root
bash-4.3#  cat /etc/group | grep docker
bash-4.3#
```

What do i need to modify to allow user 'go' to execute correctly?

Comment: Can you check `/etc/group` of the container and host? I wonder if the userid / gid line up. Also, can you list the permissions of the socket outside and inside the container?

Comment: So looks like its actually an alpine distribution. without me creating a docker group it wouldnt have existed.

Comment: @AndyShinn it's updated - looks like there is no docker group